# Cut the first word out of an array of strings and store in a new variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-manipulation, array.prototype.map

I am currently getting back an array like this:

```
['Alica Brereton,Marijuana,9.18,50',
  'William Kotai,ecstasy,19.12,20',
  'Joel Forro,heroin,91.16,5',
  'David Ernest,Methamphetamine,108.78,5',
  'David Ernest,cocaine,80,2',
  'Joel Forro,ecstasy,19.12,10',
  'Gabriella Hyde,Marijuana,9.18,10',
  'Gabriella Hyde,Methamphetamine,108.78,8',
  'Marijuana,9.18,10'
]
```

I want to cut the names at the start of each string and store in a new variable, so I would have something like this:

```
['Alica Brereton',
  'William Kotai',
  'Joel Forro',
  'David Ernest',
  'Joel Forro',
  'Gabriella Hyde'
]
```

i'm working of a text file here is my current

```
code: 
const fs = require("fs");
const data = fs.readFileSync("data.txt").toString();
const lines = data.split("\n");

let customerKeys = lines[0].replace("customer", "Total Price");
lines.shift();
console.log(customerKeys);
console.log(lines);

let array = lines.filter((str) => {
  return str !== "";
});
let arrNoSpaces = array;

console.log(arrNoSpaces);
arrNoSpaces[6].replace("Gabriella Hyde,", "");
var GabriellaExtra = arrNoSpaces[6].replace("Gabriella Hyde,", "");
console.log(GabriellaExtra);

arrNoSpaces.push(GabriellaExtra);
console.log(arrNoSpaces);
arrNoSpaces.splice(-3, 1);

console.log(arrNoSpaces);
```

Comment: You can use `.map(str => str.split(',')[0])`, but that assumes the first entry in the comma-delimited strings is always a name, which is not the case in your example. We need more information before we can answer that - we need more information about those strings.

Comment: Why is `'Joel Forro'` in your expected output twice but not `'David Ernest'`?

Comment: That's how it was presented.@NickParsons. Ideally if I could cut each Name out I can deal with duplicate names after. in the finished array I wouldn't need duplicate names but will manage if I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regular expression can match letters and spaces (not commas) from each string, mapping to a new array.

```js
const arr = ['Alica Brereton,Marijuana,9.18,50',
  'William Kotai,ecstasy,19.12,20',
  'Joel Forro,heroin,91.16,5',
  'David Ernest,Methamphetamine,108.78,5',
  'David Ernest,cocaine,80,2',
  'Joel Forro,ecstasy,19.12,10',
  'Gabriella Hyde,Marijuana,9.18,10',
  'Gabriella Hyde,Methamphetamine,108.78,8',
  'Marijuana,9.18,10'
];

const result = arr
  .map(line => line.match(/\w+ \w+/)?.[0]) // extract matches
  .filter((item, i, arr) => item && arr[i - 1] !== item) // filter out failed matches and dupes
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I was wondering if you could possible explain the .filter line?

Comment: `\w+ \w+` matches strings with words, followed by a space, followed by more words. `?.[0]` extracts the match if it exists, otherwise evaluates to `undefined`. The undefineds need to be filtered out, hence the `item &&`, and you also want to check that the previous element is not equal to the current element to filter out dupes, which the `arr[i - 1] !== item` does.

Comment: could I use a similar method to do the opposite and get all the information that isn't a name?

Comment: You could match everything afterwards in another capture group and extract that, and/or alternate the whole match with another capture group (to pick up lines that don't even start with a name like `Marijuana,9.18,10`)